# Conjointly use neo4j OGM and the neo4j java driver

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-ogm

Is this possible to conjointly use neo4j OGM and the "raw" neo4j java driver in the same project ?

My idea is to use OGM for all "CRUD" operations, but also to have access to the power of the neo4j java driver (mainly the streamed/lazy result cursor).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can go that way.

Just be aware that the OGM session has a kind of first level cache. So if you load with OGM, then update directly through drivers, then load again the same entities with OGM, you may get stale results.
In that case you might want to use OGM `session.clear()`.

Side note : there are plans to better support streaming in OGM 3.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. As it is recommended to use a single driver instance throughout an application, how can I set my driver instance to OGM ?

Comment: You can't. The OGM session will be independent from the native driver session.  Need to manage concurrent access at the application level if required (when working with same data with the 2 different mechanisms).